# urllib2 to string

Tags: python, string, urllib2

I'm using urllib2 to open a url. Now I need the html file as a string. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the string when you get it? It is possible the best solution does not involve reading the file into a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/foo/bar")
s = f.read()
# s now holds the contents of the site
```

There is more information in the [urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

`urlopen()` returns a file-like object, so Python's [file object methods](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) work.

Answer (score 16):

In python3, it should be changed to `urllib.request.openurl('http://www.example.com/').read().decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: decode('utf-8') is the easiest way, nice solution, what you get otherwise is byte object, just do type() and you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

i think in python3 the urllib.request.openurl('http://www.example.com/').read() method return in binary mode

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> s = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
>>> s
<big long string here>
```